# Pandas Count occurences data during time period improve

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In my data, each row represents a case where its attributes are Agence, GT and Agent, DateA represent the begining date and DateB is the ending date.
I have figured out a way to make a "log" of the number of cases there are running for each Agence, GT and Agent, per month and per year.

My problem is that it is extremely long (the real data has only 16,000 rows but i have to do this operation 7 times but doing one one column takes around 5 minutes) and the users won't be pleased if it takes them 1 hour to get what they want ...

How can I improve it and still get the same output ?

(Versions : python: 3.3.5 | pandas: 0.15.2 | numpy: 1.9.1)

#### This is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def getListeMonthYearBetween (catA,catB,catC,mA,yA,mB,yB) :
    mA = int(mA)
    yA=int(yA)
    mB=int(mB)
    yB=int(yB)
    df = pd.DataFrame([[catA,catB,catC,mA,yA]],columns=['Agence', 'GT','Agent','Mois','Année'])

    for i in range(0, 12*(yB-yA) +(mB-mA)):
        df2 = pd.DataFrame([[catA,catB,catC,((mA+i)%12+1),(yA+((mA+i)//12))]],columns=['Agence', 'GT','Agent','Mois','Année'])
        df=df.append(df2)

    return df

def getStatTwoDates(df, DateA, DateB, nomNewColumn):

    df[DateA] = pd.to_datetime(df[DateA])

    df[DateB] = np.where(pd.isnull(df[DateB]),pd.to_datetime('today'),df[DateB])

    df[DateB]=df[DateB].apply(getBackToDateTime)

    df=df[(~pd.isnull(df[DateA]))&(df[DateA]<df[DateB])] 

    df['YearA'], df['MonthA'],df['YearB'], df['MonthB'] = df[DateA].dt.year, df[DateA].dt.month , df[DateB].dt.year, df[DateB].dt.month 

    df=df[['Agence', 'GT','Agent','YearA','MonthA','YearB','MonthB']]
    dfStat = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Agence', 'GT','Agent','Mois','Année'])

    for row in df.itertuples() :
        data = getListeMonthYearBetween (row[1],row[2],row[3],row[5],row[4],row[7],row[6])
        dfStat=dfStat.append(data)

    dfStat = pd.DataFrame(dfStat.groupby(['Agence', 'GT','Agent','Mois','Année']).size().reset_index(name=nomNewColumn))

    return dfStat

def getBackToDateTime(x):
    if type(x) is type(pd.to_datetime('today')):
        return x
    else :
        return pd.to_datetime(x)

df = pd.DataFrame([['Agence1','A1','B1',pd.to_datetime('11/08/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('21/09/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')], 
                   ['Agence1','A1','B1',pd.to_datetime('27/02/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('21/08/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')],
                   ['Agence1','A2','B2',pd.to_datetime('11/09/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('14/01/2017', format='%d/%m/%Y')],
                   ['Agence1','A3','B3',pd.to_datetime('05/10/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('09/10/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')],
                   ['Agence1','A1','B2',pd.to_datetime('08/01/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('10/06/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')],
                   ['Agence1','A2','B2',pd.to_datetime('09/11/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('10/12/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y')],
                   ['Agence1','A3','B3',pd.to_datetime('02/09/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'),pd.to_datetime('01/02/2017', format='%d/%m/%Y')]],
                   columns=['Agence', 'GT','Agent','DateA','DateB'])

newDf=getStatTwoDates(df, 'DateA', 'DateB', 'Count')
```

#### What I have :

```
Agence      GT     Agent      DateA            DateB

Agence1     A1      B1      2016-08-11      2016-09-21
Agence1     A1      B1      2016-02-27      2016-08-21
Agence1     A2      B2      2016-09-11      2017-01-14
Agence1     A3      B3      2016-10-05      2016-10-09
Agence1     A1      B2      2016-01-08      2016-06-10
Agence1     A2      B2      2016-11-09      2016-12-10
Agence1     A3      B3      2016-09-02      2017-02-01
```

#### What I get :

```
Agence      GT      Agent   Mois    Année   Count

Agence1     A1       B1      2      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      3      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      4      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      5      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      6      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      7      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B1      8      2016      2
Agence1     A1       B1      9      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      1      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      2      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      3      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      4      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      5      2016      1
Agence1     A1       B2      6      2016      1
Agence1     A2       B2      1      2017      1
Agence1     A2       B2      9      2016      1
Agence1     A2       B2     10      2016      1
Agence1     A2       B2     11      2016      2
Agence1     A2       B2     12      2016      2
Agence1     A3       B3      1      2017      1
Agence1     A3       B3      2      2017      1
Agence1     A3       B3      9      2016      1
Agence1     A3       B3     10      2016      2
Agence1     A3       B3     11      2016      1
Agence1     A3       B3     12      2016      1
```

Comment: What are the min and max periods for your dataset? How many total months elapse?

Comment: Technically it's supposed to be dates between 2010 up to today with a duration under a year but unfortunately the data is an extract from a database filled by users so there can always be unfortunate surprises ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your method to generate a list of months for 2 datetimes can be more efficient

```
def gen_montly_list(start, end):
    start = pd.Timestamp(start.year, start.month, 1)
    end = beginning_of_next_month(end)
    return pd.DatetimeIndex(start=start, end=end, freq='1M')

def beginning_of_next_month(date):
    month = (date.month) % 12 + 1
    year = date.year if date.month != 12 else date.year + 1
    # print(year, month)
    return pd.Timestamp(year, month, 1)
```

> ```
> gen_montly_list(pd.to_datetime('11/08/2016', format='%d/%m%Y'),pd.to_datetime('21/12/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'))
> ```

```
DatetimeIndex(['2016-08-31', '2016-09-30', '2016-10-31', '2016-11-30',
               '2016-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Then for the counting, you can use a `collections.Counter`

```
def count_occurences(df):
    c = collections.Counter()
    for row in df.itertuples():
        # print(row)
        c.update(gen_montly_list(row.DateA, row.DateB))
    return c
```

so now we have to do a groupby and pass each group to this function, and aggregate this information

```
results = pd.DataFrame()

for group in df.groupby(['Agence', 'GT','Agent']):
    # print(group)
    res = pd.Series(count_occurences(group[1]))
    res = pd.DataFrame({'year':res.index.year, 'month' : res.index.month, 'count':res})
#     res.columns = ['year', 'month', 'count']
    for k, v in zip(['Agence', 'GT','Agent'], group[0]):
        res[k] = v
#     res.set_index(['Agence', 'GT','Agent', 'year', 'month', ], inplace = True)
    results = results.append(res.reset_index(drop=True))
```

> ```
> results.reindex(columns=['Agence', 'GT','Agent', 'year', 'month', 'count']).reset_index(drop=True)
> ```

```
Agence  GT  Agent   year    month   count
0   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    2   1
1   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    3   1
2   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    4   1
3   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    5   1
4   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    6   1
5   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    7   1
6   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    8   2
7   Agence1     A1  B1  2016    9   1
8   Agence1     A1  B2  2016    1   1
9   Agence1     A1  B2  2016    2   1
10  Agence1     A1  B2  2016    3   1
11  Agence1     A1  B2  2016    4   1
12  Agence1     A1  B2  2016    5   1
13  Agence1     A1  B2  2016    6   1
14  Agence1     A2  B2  2016    9   1
15  Agence1     A2  B2  2016    10  1
16  Agence1     A2  B2  2016    11  2
17  Agence1     A2  B2  2016    12  2
18  Agence1     A2  B2  2017    1   1
19  Agence1     A3  B3  2016    9   1
20  Agence1     A3  B3  2016    10  2
21  Agence1     A3  B3  2016    11  1
22  Agence1     A3  B3  2016    12  1
23  Agence1     A3  B3  2017    1   1
24  Agence1     A3  B3  2017    2   1
```

> ```
> results.set_index(['Agence', 'GT','Agent', 'year', 'month'])
> ```

generates a DataFrame with a MultiIndex

Comment: Great idea ! I'm currently trying to use it but count_occurences returns `Counter()` which lead res to be an empty Series because  gen_montly_list returns  `Length: 0, Freq: M, Timezone: pytz.FixedOffset(0)` .  I think it comes from the values of start and end (they are indeed type `<class 'pandas.tslib.Timestamp'> ` but when i try to print them i get `offset must be a timedelta representing a whole number of minutes` ( I have modified that : `start = pd.Timestamp(pd.to_datetime(start).year, pd.to_datetime(start).month, 1)` )

Comment: as long as `start` < `end` in `gen_montly_list` it should return a non-empty Index. In your code you do some checks to see that `DateA` < `DateB` which I did not integrate. These you will have to do yourself

Comment: I already have `df=df[(~pd.isnull(df['DateA']))&(df['DateA']<df['DateB'])] ` at the beggining just to be sure. It seems that it mistakes Timestamps for a Timedelta because even `print(pd.Timestamp(2012, 5, 1))` get me `ValueError: offset must be a timedelta representing a whole number of minutes`. I'm going to keep searching so I can try your solution. Thanks

Comment: does `gen_montly_list(pd.to_datetime('11/08/2016', format='%d/%m%Y'),pd.to_datetime('21/12/2016', format='%d/%m/%Y'))` work?

Comment: No it doesn't work either ... I get the same error `offset must be a timedelta representing a whole number of minutes`.

Comment: It was the Timestamp that he didn't like. I used `pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(start).year)+str(pd.to_datetime(start).month)+str(1), format='%Y%m%d')` and `pd.to_datetime(str(year)+str(month)+str(1), format='%Y%m%d')` instead and it works like a charm !! Thanks a lot !

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(str(pd.to_datetime(start).year)+"/"+str(pd.to_datetime(start).month)+"/"+str(1), format='%Y/%m/%d')` and `pd.to_datetime(str(year)+"/"+str(month)+"/"+str(1), format='%Y/%m/%d')` are safer to use ( and that's really fast under 2 minutes for the 7 operations !! )